How to imitate nfc tag scanned with ADB tools or software
Good afternoon. Brief story: My institution has several nfc tags in building which have to be scanned with specific app built and used in Microsoft PowerApps. Now, my question is, if it's possible to "imitate" that the specific nfc tag, with specific uid and data was scanned via ADB tools using windows and performin so on my android device.
To be honest, Im not really familiar with the topic, but I really hope to find some help here. Maybe you could suggest anothe methods of solution, maybe there is already written application which imitates that an nfc tag was scanned for whole android system? Maybe there is any AC122U emulator which also provides opportunity to scan non-physically-existing nfc tag for Windows or Android? Any other suggestions are welcome. Best wishes.
After some research, I found kind of solution but it didn't work so far:
adb shell am start -W -a android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED --es "uid" "someuid" -t "text/plain" --es "android.nfc.extra.TEXT" "sometext" -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -n com.microsoft.msapps/.MainActivity
After executing this command, powerapps shows that tag was scanned incorrectly.
